# EventListener in angular with Callback gives error in firefox ERROR ReferenceError: "event is not defined"

Tags: event-handling, addeventlistener, infinite-scroll, angular8

I want to load data on window scroll event
this is my code:

```
 private scrollChangeCallback: () => void;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.scrollChangeCallback = () => this.handleWindowScroll(event);
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrollChangeCallback, true);
 }

  handleWindowScroll = (event): void => {
    const total = this.sites.length;
    const page = this.getPageForIndex(total);
     let bottomPosition = event.srcElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight + 25;
     let scrolledHeight = event.srcElement.scrollHeight;
     if (this.sites != null && bottomPosition > scrolledHeight && !this.theEnd && total >= this.pageSize) {
      this.siteRepositoryService.loadSites(this.searchTerm, page);
       this.subscribeOnScroll();
   }
 }
```

It gives error on firefox ReferenceError: Event is not defined.
I have try every possible solution and spend enough time for this but it's not working can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve this error by two ways:

1. Update firefox
2. User ngAfterViewInit instead of ngOnInit